# AsyncTask show loading progress and return a value jsoup

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, jsoup

I'm working on a web application that will parse the site and load the news dynamically into the CardView. For now it works and does all the needed stuff. But it's not exactly what I want.
Here's a piece of my code to understand what I am talking about:

```
public class NewsPage extends ActionBarActivity {
    List<NewCard> listNC = new ArrayList<NewCard>();


    class NewsParser extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,List<NewCard>> {
        Document doc;
        List<NewCard> nc = new ArrayList<NewCard>();
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
           // progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(NewsPage.this, "Parsing the site", "Please wait while the information is loading...", true);
        };

        @Override
        protected List<NewCard> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
//some code skipped
                    nc.add(new NewCard(forHeader.html(), forDesc, URLforImg, forHeader.attr("href")));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return nc;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String[] s) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();//This method is being called out by new <class name>.execute();
            //listNC = new ArrayList<NewCard>(nc);
        }
    }
```

In here I am retrieving article headlines for further opening.

This is my onCreate() method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_page);
    RecyclerView recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recList.setLayoutManager(llm);

    try {
        NewsParser np = new NewsParser();
        np.execute();
        listNC = np.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    NewsAdapter na = new NewsAdapter(listNC);
    size = na.sizes;
    recList.setAdapter(na);
```

I'm using my adapter to fill the cards with information and to handle onClick events.

**My question is this:**

- I need to retrieve information from my AsyncTask in order to create a
  list of cards (in this case I need an amount of cards) and I am not
  sure I can go on without returning values. But it makes my app freeze
  and not show any interface until the action is completed. How is it
  better to handle? Maybe I need to make it all different? How do I
  load news headlines separately (not all together but in order)? And
  what kind of loop (I don't know how to call it correctly) do I need
  to add news as they load (because my program doesn't work if it
  doesn't have the list before doing UI stuff)?

I've tried to tell every detail from my code and if it's needed I might add my Adapter code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UI is freezing because your `get()` method in the `try` block is blocking waiting on the `AsyncTask` to complete.  This defeats the purpose of even using the `AsyncTask`.  Instead, create your `Adapter` before you kick off the `AsyncTask` and then in the `onPostExecute()` set the data for the adapter to be the new result and call the adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.  This will cause the UI to pick up the changes.

Be careful with your use of `AsyncTask` or any other threading mechanism.  They are not lifecycle aware, so if the `onPostExecute()` method has any strong references to the `Activity` or its inner member fields and tries to directly use them it could run into state exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried what you suggested but I am not sure I have done it as it needs to be done. http://pastebin.com/nUcbz2j9
It still won't work for me. I think I have messed up with the order of actions. Would you mind pointing my mistake out please?

Comment: It's because the `onPostExecute()` is creating a new adapter object and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on it rather than submitting a new `List` object to the existing adapter.  I'd suggest reworking your `doInBackground()` so it returns a new `List` object with content.  Then in `onPostExecute()` submit that new list to your existing `Adapter` (create a custom `swapData()` method or something similar.)  After the new data has been giving to the adapter you can call `notify...`.  You may find this article useful for understanding `AsyncTask`: http://po.st/Cei3m2